# Get installed software in other machines without enabling Remote registry

Tags: c#, wpf, remote-registry

I need to get the installed program list of all machines in my LAN from a machine.

I can access the remote registry through the "RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey" option, 
But I need to enable the remote registry service on all machines in my LAN. I think it is a security violation.

Is there any options to collect the software installed in other machines without enabling the remote registry service?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the settings of all computers. There is no guarantee that some approach would work for 100%. Every approach, where you want some access to computers, could be security risk.
The safest approach is IMHO install some sort of service to all monitored computers which sends list of installed apps to you.